# Archive failed : Fastlane with Ionic 3

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic3, fastlane

I try to deploy my Ionic 3 App on Testflight in a first time.

But When I run my command : "sudo fastlane beta" I always have this error :

```
Check dependencies

Code Signing Error: No profile for team '(TEAM_ID)' matching 'match AppStore (APP_BUNDLE)' found:  Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '(TEAM_ID)/match AppStore (APP_BUNDLE)'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.1'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

I really don't know what I have to do to solve this.

What I have done :

In first, I follow this to generate my certifcates and my profils
https://codesigning.guide/
I haven't problem with this. I can see my profils on my account developper iOS.

So I Installed plugin fastlane Ionic. And I edited my Fastfile like this :

```
fastlane_version "2.68.0"
generated_fastfile_id "(FAST LANE ID)"

default_platform :ios

desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Apple TestFlight"
desc "This will also make sure the profile is up to date"
lane :beta do
  match(type: "appstore")
  ionic(platform: 'ios')
  pilot(ipa: ENV['CORDOVA_IOS_RELEASE_BUILD_PATH'])
end
```

My App File :

```
app_identifier "(APP_BUNDLE)"
apple_id "(MY APPLE ID)"
team_id "(TEAM_ID)"
```

But when I run : sudo fastlane beta , this step fail : 
`ionic cordova compile ios --release --device -- --packageType=app-store --developmentTeam=(TEAM_ID) --provisioningProfile=(PROFILE_GUID)`

EDIT : My Ionic Info :

```
cli packages: (/Users/ox/Documents/Mobile/ox/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.0
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 5.1.0 
    Node       : v6.11.3
    npm        : 5.6.0 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

**EDIT**

I remove and add again my platform ios :
ionic cordova platforms remove ios
ionic cordova platforms add ios

I tried to run fastlane beta. I keep my error but a little bit different :

```
Code Signing Error: No profile for team '(TEAM_ID)' matching '(PROFILE_UUID)' found:  Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '(TEAM_ID)/(PROFILE_UUID)'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.1'
```

I check in xcode and I have this errors :

[image]

Comment: What is your `ionic info` output? It can give important environment information. Best edit your question to add it.

Comment: That looks fine, and although I posted an answer the `ionic cordova compile ios` command your current setup is producing actually looks fine, `release: true` is the default anyway. Try it anyway and let me know if it works, otherwise we will have to keep looking...

Comment: Did you do any strange things with the `ios` project before? Maybe remove it with `ionic cordova platform remove ios` and add it back with `ionic cordova platform add ios` again and try to run the lane once more.

Comment: Humm I don't think. I just have to had capabilities Push Notifications and Background Modes. But I tried without them too. I will try to remove iOS platform again.

Comment: You should not have to use Xcode at all normally (besides your Push and Background Mode - but even that you can probably do via Fastlane). I would suggest to try it with a new, "virgin" app newly created with `ionic start` and see if this works for you.

Comment: Is it possible that the identifier in my Apple Dev account is bad ? I created it manually and I don't if Fastlane will generate it if I delete it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not do `sudo fastlane...`! try to go with `fastlane beta` if it requires root - probably you have to reinstall the tools. Also, recommended way is to use [`bundler`](http://bundler.io) to manage your ruby dependencies
2. Try to do Archive command in Xcode and make sure you able to build and sign project manually
3. run `fastlane match` command to get ur provisioning profile (you might be asked to login to iTunesConnect...)

   - in case match fails - please, use parameters to specify ur team/app: `fastlane action match` - this command with show you the options you have
4. try `fastlane beta` *no sudo!*

Comment: I had a lot of problem with my older Mac. My compagny permit me to change it and in don't have any problem anymore with fastlane. With my new installation, I don't have to use sudo.
Sure, sudo is the devil. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build for the app store, your have to also create a `release` (and optimally `prod`) build with `ionic()`. Otherwise the Xcode project is setup in the wrong way for the certificate you are setting via `match()`.

This should work for you:

```
lane :beta do
  match(type: "appstore")
  ionic(
    platform: 'ios',
    prod: true,
    release: true
  )
  pilot(ipa: ENV['CORDOVA_IOS_RELEASE_BUILD_PATH'])
end
```

Also see https://ionic.zone/fastlane/build-your-project-with-ionic-plugin#ios-release-build

Comment: I tried this but I had excatly the same error. I already tried to remove and add again platform but nothing better ...